# What IDE is recommended for React Native?

Tags: javascript, facebook, ide, cross-platform, react-native

I'm looking to use React Native for app development. Since it is free and an open source, cross-platform environment. The question is: what IDE can I use to write and build and do everything in it?
Appreciate the help.

Comment: Officially [Nuclide](http://nuclide.io/) But I hear visual studio code is worth a look. I personally use sublime

Comment: Oh ok!! Thanks a lot

Comment: I recommend and I personally use IntelliJ IDEA by JetBrains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially [Nuclide](http://nuclide.io/) But I hear visual studio code is worth a look. I personally use sublime

Answer (score 1):

Since I use their IDEs for other languages too I use PhpStore/WebStorm from JetBrains. It's a very good set of tools. As an added bonus Android Studio is using the JetBrains IDE as a basis as well. So you'll feel right at home there. On the downside you have to pay and they just this month switch over to a subscription model. But as a professional developer I'm willing to pay for tools that make me more productive.

Answer (score 0):

sublime with [Babel syntax highlighting](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime). :)

Answer (score 0):

My answer on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-editor-to-write-React-and-React-Native-code/answer/Akash-Patel-115).

Nuclide still doesn’t have a proper windows support.

SublimeText may be a great editor for JS but with React code, the color scheme gives up like this:

[image]

I tried [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for a while but it lacks some standard IDE functionalities so I moved on to [Atom](https://atom.io/). It simple to install/customize and it works! So far it’s my favorite editor for React development.

Answer (score 0):

Windows I use sublime text3 as IDE,Plugin:

`ReactJS: support React development, code hints, highlighting`

`Emmet: front-end development necessary.`

`Terminal: open the terminal in sublime and navigate to the current directory, artifacts, mac shortcut keys: command + shift + T`

`React-native-snippets: react native snippet`

The following options, to solve the grammar check error

> Open the menu `view`, `Syntax` -> `Open all with current extension as ...` -> `Babel` -> `JavaScript (Babel)`, select babel as the default javascript open syntax
>   Be sure to choose Open all with current extension as ... .

Mac I use Atom ,Plugin:Nuclide

Answer (score 0):

I personally use **IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition** it's Excellent try it.

But officially **Nuclide** but it still has not proper support for windows.

Comment: why down vote?  IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition providing full support for JavaScript, React.js, React Native and Vue.js.